# EF 6.0 with Symmetric key encryption

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

In my application I am using ASP.NET MVC with EF6.0. Initially we were saving data as a plain text. But because of some security reasons we had to implement Symmetric Key encryption with certificate on our database.

And now because of that one we had to execute below commands before executing any LINQ query in my application:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyEncryptionTest
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE EncryptionTest;
```

And once query is executed below statements should be executed:

```
CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKeyEncryptionTest
```

As EF opens and closes new connection at each query is there any way i can execute these statements before and after the execution of the query?

Comment: Your DbContext has a constructor and a virtual Dispose. Try those.

Comment: can you please provide me reference links?